# "File not found: lib" when switching to older rails version using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I currently have rails 3.0.3 and am trying to download and use version 3.0.1. I've downloaded and installed RVM and inputted the following code in Terminal (I have a Mac OS X 10.6.5):

```
rvm use 1.8.7
rvm gemset create rails3.0.1
rvm 1.8.7@rails3.0.1
sudo gem install rails --version=3.0.1
```

I use sudo gems because of the user permissions, or my lack there of. Anyway, after I enter the last line of code: ***"sudo gem install rails --version=3.0.1"*** I get the following error:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
File not found: lib
```

Not only can I apparently not able to switch versions of rails, even though it appears as though I have multiple versions installed, every time I try to check to see what version of rails I currently have I get the following result:

```
rails -v
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find  RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Also, I've already installed Rdoc and Xcode (I've done research and other suggestions pointed to installing both). I'm a RoR newbie, and especially an RVM newbie, so I would love an explanation and a solution to this madness.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you went off the rails (ha-ha) right here:

```
sudo gem install rails --version=3.0.1
```

The [RVM documentation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) has this to say about that:

> DO NOT use sudo...
>
> to work with RVM gems. When you do
>   sudo you are running commands as root,
>   another user in another shell and
>   hence all of the setup that RVM has
>   done for you is ignored while the
>   command runs under sudo (such things
>   as GEM_HOME, etc...). So to reiterate,
>   as soon as you 'sudo' you are running
>   as the root system user which will
>   clear out your environment as well as
>   any files it creates are not able to
>   be modified by your user and will
>   result in strange things happening.
>   (You will start to think that someone
>   has a voodoo doll of your
>   application...)

Comment: Interesting! You don't by any chance have an idea how to run commands as root without using sudo? Whenever I try to install a previous version of rails using gems I get a permissions error.

Comment: I'm guessing that happens because you previously installed Rails with `sudo`. One option is to remove Rails with `sudo gem uninstall rails`, then install again without `sudo`, which should allow RVM to pull it into your gemset.

Comment: That sounds right but my only issue is that I am only able to install using sudo. I don't know how to run commands as root and as a result don't have permission to install rails without sudo. Any suggestions? When I typed <sudo gem uninstall rails> it displayed all of the rails version I have installed on my system, so it looks as if the previous rails version installation worked successfully. However, I am now running into </Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)> when I run the rails server...you're clearly right

Comment: So, I uninstalled all of my rails versions and then re-installed rails using "gem install rails" and then followed the same steps as above "rvm use 1.8.7; rvm gemset create rails3.0.1; rvm 1.8.7@rails3.0.1; gem install rails --version=3.0.1" And lo and behold, it worked! However, I am still getting an error towards the end of the installation. When Terminal gets to this line I get an error: "Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
File not found: lib"
Thanks for all your help! And I would appreciate it that much more if you can solve this mystery!

Comment: Does `rails -v` still give you an error? If not, I think the install of the code went OK, even if the install of the documentation failed. Googling the error shows that a number of people reported the same issue for beta versions of Rails 3. Bottom line: unless you need the ri docs, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, rails -v works now, you must be right about the issue. Thanks for your help!