# problem in installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi all i am getting problem while installing rails in  by gem :
i have written in terminal

> gem install rails

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.3...
File not found: lib
```

what i need to do next and how to install rails using gem.

Comment: Is Rails being installed? Try running `rails new sample`. It looks like just the documentation is having troubles...

Comment: @yosanu: Here is similar thread in case you are using RVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363264/file-not-found-lib-when-switching-to-older-rails-version-using-rvm

Comment: @Kevin Rails is not installed . I am trying to install it by gem command . And rails new sample will not work.

Comment: @Heikki which one is better using rvm or direct install ?

Comment: @yosanu RVM and project specific gemsets keep things in good order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I continued with the error. I do not see anything breaking. And I can code peacefully. So, probably you do not need to worry.

---

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libopenssl-ruby libfcgi-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby irb rubygems ruby1.8-dev
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install rails
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

---

If you dont find path do this: (for Unix based systems)

Quoted from the book, but anyone else would suggest the same

```
If you can’t find the rails command, you may need to add 
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin to your PATH environment variable.
 You can do this by adding a line to your .bashrc file:


export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

---

OK as [aditya sanghi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523692/aditya-sanghi) has mentioned, I do lack rdoc gem-- so probably running this will help

```
gem install rdoc rails
```

Comment: but when i am trying to run rails command its saying "you can install it by sudo apt-get install"
rails command is not working

Comment: whenever I am on a new System, I open Rails in Action book and run these. And get going. I am updating the steps in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when you dont have the "rdoc" gem installed. Can you do a "gem list" and show us a list of gems installed?

Try running "gem install rdoc rails".