# Installing Rails 3.0.3 on mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to get Rails 3.0.x installed on my machine. The first time i tried it, it gave me the following error: `cant find lib .` So i found the rails3.0.3 gem folder and made the lib folder. I can install the gem correctly but when i type the following command `rails -v` It throws the following error.

```
Daniel-MacBook-Pro:~ Daniel$ sudo gem install rails
Password:
Successfully installed rails-3.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.0.3...
Daniel-MacBook-Pro:~ Daniel$ rails -v
    /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:233:in `activate': can't activate i18n (~> 0.4.1, runtime)     for ["mail-2.2.9", "actionmailer-3.0.3", "rails-3.0.3"], already activated     i18n-0.5.0beta3 for ["activemodel-3.0.3", "actionpack-3.0.3", "rails-3.0.3"] (Gem::LoadError)
     from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
     from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
     from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
     from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
     from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
 from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
 from /usr/bin/rails:18
Daniel--MacBook-Pro:~ Daniel$
```

How can i fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you do not have `rdoc` installed. It does not hamper any functionality during development. If if you do want you can try this

```
   sudo gem install rdoc
```

see details here [problem in installing rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539924/problem-in-installing-rails/4539969#4539969)

Comment: This throws up a new error: Successfully installed rails-3.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.3...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `coverage_level=' for nil:NilClass
Daniel--MacBook-Pro:~ Daniel$

Comment: you may want to start over -- as mentioned in the link provided. I have tried the same in Ubuntu and got it working.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [RVM](http://rvm.io) and stop installing gems with sudo!

Comment: Why should i/we stop installing gems with sudo?

Comment: RVM allows you to install gems as per project basis and have multiple ruby version installed.